# I can't set a value in a class

Tags: java

I made two classes. The first one is the `Player` class and the second the `Bag`. What I want is to print the score of the player in `main()`. In `Bag`, I count the score and I want to set it in `Player`. This is a part of the `Bag` class

```
 public void count( int number)
 { ............. 
   scr=k*2;//gives an int
   setScore(scr);//set the score in Player class
 }
```

**Player:**

```
public class Player {

public Player() {
}

private String name;
private int score;

public Player(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}
 public String getName() { 
     return name;
 }

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}
```

In main() I try to print the score with this code but I can't:

```
Player p=new Player();
System.out.println( p.getScore());
```

It returns me `score=0` (which I set it at the begging of main)
I hope that you understand what I want to say.

Comment: where do you call set? you just create a player and print it.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You ask questions, we answer them. The defining characteristic of a question is that it ends with a question mark ('?', ASCII code 0x3F, on most keyboards it can be found right next to the right shift key.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, the Bag class should have a reference to the Player class. So essentially you should change your code to follow the below pattern

```
class Bag
{
  private Player p;

  public void setPlayer(Player pp)
  {
    p=pp;
  }

  public Player getPlayer()
  {
    return p;
  }

 public void count( int number)
 { 
   scr=k*2;//gives an int
   p.setScore(scr);//set the score in Player class
 }
}
```

And your main method

```
Player p=new Player();
Bag b=new Bag();
b.setPlayer(p);
b.count(5);
System.out.println( p.getScore());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the score for a particular player, you need to call `setScore` *on that object*. For example:

```
public void count(int number)
{
    scr = k * 2;
    player.setScore(scr);
}
```

where `player` is a variable of type `Player`.

However, that won't affect the score for a *new* player:

```
Player p=new Player();
System.out.println(p.getScore());
```

That will still print 0, because the score for the *new* player is still 0. You need to print out the score for the player whose score you set within `count`.

It's hard to give you more specific information than this as we don't know how the rest of your application is meant to hold together, but assuming each player has an independent score, you should think about *which* player's score you want to change in the `count` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change this.

```
public void count(int number)
{ 
    Player p=new Player();
    scr=k*2;//gives an int
    p.setScore(scr);//set the score in Player class
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to explain without observing your full application.

Answer (score 0):

The player and bag are different class, suppose you want to do some calculation in bag class that will refer to player class and those values will need in player class, bag class need to have player reference. so that you need to do some change in both classes.

change count method as like below

> public void count(Player p, int number)  { .............
>   scr=k*2;//gives an int    p.setScore(scr);//set the score in Player
>   class  }

and change the main method as like below

> Player p=new Player(); Bag b = new Bag(); b.count(p,5);
>   System.out.println( p.getScore());